# i need an sp to select or update my tables and for that i have to enter multiple values for single variable how can i do that?

Tags: sql-server-2008

desperately need an sp to pass mutiple values for the single variable like `@list` is a variable and the values I'm putting for it are '`1,3,4,5,66`' and I need information from the table realated to these id's:

```
SELECT T.C.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS [id]
    INTO #tblPersons
    FROM (SELECT CAST ('<Name>' + REPLACE(@empid, ',', '</Name><Name>') + '</Name>' AS XML) AS [Names]) AS A
    cross APPLY Names.nodes('/Name') as T(C)
```

I'm using this in my sp but I'm getting difficulty for passing this for the mutiple values.

Comment: Have you thought of using a table valued parameter to pass information to the stored procedure? Take a look here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/passing-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/168

Comment: could you please elaborate your answer by giving any examples i'm not able to understand the information given in the link above

Comment: Did the answer below help you?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using table variables to pass data to a stored procedure. Example:

**Setup**

```
CREATE TYPE EmpIdValuesType AS TABLE
  (                     
        [EmpID] [int]NOT NULL
  )

CREATE TABLE Employee
(
  EmpID INT,
  Name varchar(20)
 )

INSERT INTO Employee 
Values
 (1, 'test1'),
 (2, 'test2'),
 (3, 'test3'),
 (4, 'test4'),
 (5, 'test5'),
 (6, 'test6'),
 (7, 'test7');

Create Procedure usp_GetEmployees
(
  @TableVariable EmpIdValuesType READONLY
)
AS
  SELECT *
  FROM Employee
  INNER JOIN @TableVAriable TV
    ON Employee.EmpId = TV.EmpId
```

Now you can insert rows into a temporary table variable of type EmpIdValuesType and pass the variable to the stored procedure:

**Calling the Stored Procedure**

```
DECLARE @empIds AS EmpIdValuesType

INSERT INTO @empIds(EmpID) Values (1), (2), (5)

Exec usp_GetEmployees @empIds;
```

And here are the results:
[image: SQL Results]

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c2eb/8/0)

Comment: Next time it might be a little easier to paste in the "Plaintext" or "Markdown" output format for your SQL Fiddle results :)  See the down array next to the "Run SQL" button on SQL Fiddle.  Cheers!

Comment: Jake, yes I saw how to do that later, this was my first SQLFiddle. Thanks