# Input multiple individual values in 1 input text field in visual studio 2010 and send to SQL as part of the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Using the input values from 1 text field (7171, 7496, 7134, 7108, 7105, 7353), how do I create an IN listing for the WHERE clause of my SQL statement.  The input text box can have 1 number or multiple numbers that would need to be included in the WHERE-IN clause

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause

Comment: Have a look at my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252072/i-need-an-sp-to-select-or-update-my-tables-and-for-that-i-have-to-enter-multiple/13259949#13259949 which shows how to pass a table variable to a stored procedure to do exactly this

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @query as nvarchar(max)
declare @text varchar(200)

set @text='80000, 8600'
set @query='select * from Employee where [emp_salary] in ('+@text+')'
--[emp_salary] is integer field 
exec sp_executesql @query
```